# Anonymous Search Error

Tags: 2013, search, anonymous-authentication

Searching Anonymously returns no results.  I have the QueryParameterTemplate.xml setup correctly.

Call:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&querytemplatepropertiesurl='spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml'
```

**Error**: `The security token request cannot be completed`

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: check this solution https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/84f6bf27-b8dc-40b5-97a3-129f2f331818/search-result-page-throw-error-for-anonymous-user?forum=sharepointsearch looks like some problem with account

Comment: thank you but  `impersonate="true"` is already set.